# CSS opacity to parent not to childs

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to not apply opacity for child element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182304/how-to-not-apply-opacity-for-child-element)

Which is the best practice to set opacity:0.5; to the parent element like:

```
<div>
<span></span>

<span></span>

<span></span>
</div>
```

if i set opacity to the  element this will set the same rule to the children elements, is there any trick to avoid the children inherition?

Comment: You can't stop inheritance. You can however override it. Setting opacity: 0.5 on div will be inherited by the spans and to counter it you need to set opacity:1 on spans.

Comment: `opacity` is not inherited, so that won't work either.

Comment: @BoltClock http://jsfiddle.net/UHNtH/ check font-color

Comment: childs inherit in their rules as i see, font-color for example

Comment: @BoltClock: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-opacity-that-doesnt-affect-child-elements/

Comment: @Jawad i was asking my self if there was trick to avoid that effectively

Comment: And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770341/i-do-not-want-to-inherit-the-child-opacity-from-the-parent-in-css

Comment: And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636871/is-opacity-is-inherited-in-a-div

Comment: http://piddmedia.com/tutorials/cross-browser-opacity-that-stops-inheritance/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css3 background-color:rgba(122,122,0,0.5); the last value is the opacity, and it dont force the child elements to get it.

Comment: This works. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qXJJm/1/).

Comment: For cross-browser support, use PNG 24 image instead. RGBA is for CSS3 compatible only.

Answer (score 0):

use rgba,

```
 background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
```

Comment: sure this is what i like to avoid